# VTK UnstructuredGrid Offset coordinates

Tags: python, vtk

I read through a PYTHON script an unstructuredGrid which format is vtk. I'd like to offset every points of this UGrid. I mean i have a x, y and z offset which I would like to apply to the UGrid so that I can obtain the same origin for two different mesh. I can't directly assign this offset since the coordinates are tuples. Any advice welcolmed.

Thx,

Arnaud

Comment: Do you just read a vtk file and want to offset the points before writing again to a file, or do you read the UG-data to be directly inserted into the vtk pipeline? For the latter you could use the vtkTransformFilter (e.g. adapt the following http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/TransformFilter)

Comment: Yes. Indeed I'd like to offset the points before writing to a file ! Any idea ?

Comment: Well, if you have an ascii vtk file you could simple read the file line by line and offset the points before writing again to a file. This should be no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I use quite often is the following function to read an ascii vtk file, process the points and write it again to a new file.

```
def offsetVTK(infilename, outfilename, offset):
    outfil = open(outfilename,'w')
    with open(infilename,'r') as infil:
        lin = 1
        while lin:
            lin = infil.readline()
            if lin.lower().startswith('points'):
                numpt = int(lin.split()[1])
                outfil.write(lin)
                for i in xrange(numpt):
                    outfil.write('{0[0]} {0[1]} {0[2]}\n'.format(
                       np.array(infil.readline().split(),dtype=float) + offset))
            else:
                outfil.write(lin)
    outfil.close()

offsetVTK('ray.vtk','ray_off.vtk', np.array([100,0,0]))
```

Originally, I used it to rotate and shear the grid, however applying an offset is even easier.